# Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a delete button that deletes a row from my database using jquery and ajax. when i click the button i get the error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined.`

It then higlights `var del_id = element.attr("id");`

```
 <a href="#" id="14" class="delbutton"><i class ="fa fa-trash"></i></a>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    $(".delbutton").click(function(){
    var del_id = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + del_id;
    if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this?"))
    {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "feed/deletepost",
    data: info,
    success: function(){
    }
    });
    $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
    .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    }
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Well, the error is pretty self-explanatory. You don't define `element`.

Comment: What are you expecting element to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `element` is not defined :D try this instead:

```
$(".delbutton").click(function(){
  var del_id = $(this).attr("id");....
```

greetings